# Chnage driver xhci_hcd to ehci_hcd in HP Chromebox

Tags: xhci-hcd

I cannot change the xHCI to eHCI in Bios.

Please help me how we can change the Kernel driver xhci_hcd to ehci_hcd permemtatly in HP chromebox and OS is Linux Ubuntu 18.04 Sever.

Comment: Why would you do it?

Comment: When i connect to USB, we are getting "Not Enough USB Controller Resources for this device".

Comment: Why are you thinking `ehci` will give you more resources? `xhci` is a USB 3.0 driver, `ehci` is a USB 2.0.

Comment: XHCI is limiting at 96 endpoint. EHCI is more